# MySQL Error in the FROM statement: FROM is not a valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

In this error it indicates that the

"FROM is not a valid input at this position".

Here is the code which is an insert statement with JOIN clause

```
UPDATE phpcollab.projects

SET ph.APPROVED='2',
    pd.currentBudget = pd.currentbudget - ph.totalvalue

FROM phpcollab.projects pp JOIN phpcollab.photo ph
                             ON pp.projectID = ph.id
WHERE ID='1';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MySQL's update-join syntax doesn't use a `from` clause:

```
UPDATE phpcollab.projects pp
JOIN   phpcollab.photo ph ON pp.id = ph.projectID
SET    ph.APPROVED = '2',
       pp.currentBudget = pp.currentbudget - ph.totalvalue
WHERE  ph.id = '1';
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could call the data from the other table? Because I want to subtract a data from the photos table to the projects table

Comment: @MarcoM. Of course - you can use table aliases and relate to data in the other table(s) like my example shows.